# Eevee (Blender 2.90): How to create an color changing flickering light, which renders fast?

Tags: eevee-render-engine

For eevee viewport rendering I need a light, which flickers in red, green and blue. The mixed light components are giving the wanted color change.
Eevee does not support shader nodes for light. So I created a red, a blue and a green area light at the same position and pointing towarts the same direction, animated the power of each and gave the f-curve a noise modifier each with different seed values.
"Works"....but is inacceptable slow (Nvidia RTX 2070 SUPER, RYZEN 5 3600, Linux, 32GB RAM).

Are there other more efficient methods to acchieve the same effect without that time penalty?

N.B.: The light should lit the sorroundings.

Comment: Do you have an example scene/file? Your hardware is pretty good, so maybe there is a performance issue somewere else. Or im missing something, because this shouldnt be that slow in my opinion.

Comment: do you mean that it's slow actually rendering with eevee or just previewing with the viewport set to Rendered? if the later, would it work disabling those lights in the viewport? (since the result colour is gonna be random anyway)

Comment: I am not allowed to distribute the original file. I tried to strip down the whole thing to the important parts - but then the effect does not show. The slowdown happens in the viewport when animated as when doing "render viewport animation". I cannot check for cycles, because I had setup all materials for eevee.